# PyQT4 installation in nokia n79

Tags: python, user-interface, mobile, pyqt4

I am just newbie to python and now, I am writing an interface in Nokia n79 phone. My question is that is it possible to install PyQt4 in nokia n79 or possible to run PyQt4 in Nokia n79. If yes, how? Is there anyway that I could take as a reference or take as an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are python packages for symbian, look for python for S60. It's an open source project. Download the sis file to your phone and install it...  good luck.